# Excel 2010 double variable run-time error 16

Tags: excel, runtime-error, excel-2010, vba

We have a problem running this code on one user machine in our office - all other user machines run it fine (Windows XP operating systems, Excel 2010 Standard or Professional) - this machine is Windows XP, running Excel 2010 Professional. Run-time error 16 appears on the line marked --> Problem appears to be the variable i - highlight tip shows i = -1.#IND

```
Sub FormatSheet(strResultSheet As String)
    Dim oCol As Excel.Range
    Dim i As Double
    Dim R As String
    Dim iColumn As Integer

    ' Special rountine to convert text column into numeric
    Sheets(strResultSheet).Select
    iColumn = 0
--> For i = 1 To Worksheets(strResultSheet).Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column
        If UCase(Cells(1, i).Text) = "QUANTITY" Then
            iColumn = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Sheets(strResultSheet).Select
    If iColumn > 0 Then
        Columns(iColumn).Select
        Selection.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
        Selection.HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignRight
        For i = 2 To Sheets(strResultSheet).Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
            If Cells(i, iColumn).Text <> "" Then
                Cells(i, iColumn).Value = Cells(i, iColumn).Value * 1
            End If
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

Anyone know what we need to do to fix user machine to handle? Macro is embedded in third-party daily email so cannot adjust code to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
Sub FormatSheet(strResultSheet As String)

    Dim rng As Range, lastRow As Integer

    With Sheets(strResultSheet)
        .Select
        Set rng = .Rows("1:1").Find("QUANTITY")

        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            rng.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
            rng.HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignRight

            lastRow = Cells(65000, rng.Column).End(xlUp).Row
            For i = 2 To lastRow
                Cells(i, rng.Column).Value = Cells(i, rng.Column).Value * 1
            Next
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```